# Duplicate application of the same mockup class

Tags: jmockit

When does the below error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate application of the same
>   mock-up class_ exception

occurs?

```
@Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    new MockUp<URL>() {
      @Mock
      public void $init(String location) {}
    }.getMockInstance();
    new MockUp<CommunicationUtils>() {
      @Mock
      public void $clinit() {}
    }.getMockInstance();
  }
```

At line number 7, I am getting this exception.

Comment: First, I have no idea which line is line 7. Second, there is no need to call `getMockInstance()` unless you are [faking an interface](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#interfaces). From the moment you instantiate a `MockUp<T>`, all instances of T within the current test will be fakes. Get rid of the calls to `getMockInstance()` and see if that helps.

Comment: I have updated JARs version of Jmockit from 1.29 to 1.30 and now I am not getting this exception. Thanks for the answer. It helps.